# Javascript : issues with Promise.all and json() being logged as "not a function"

Tags: javascript, json, async-await, fetch-api

I'm having some issues with the "Promise.all" method.
Bascially, I have an array of URL (here is a simple one if you guys want to test :

```
const urlArray = [
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/985adeec-a1fd-4e79-899d-10c54b6af299",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/4c54ee58-86df-3ba5-aaad-6b284293141b",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/cd8e5736-ec8c-3c4d-a231-ac097877d87a",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/b9b7641f-9389-342e-8be9-e463bd52fdb9",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/b6206cad-15eb-3a95-b67e-1f49849e5fbd",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/db425753-965f-4881-955b-8cd3ef65d1e6",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/fa4f230a-e78c-32a8-bec8-3a7425aba9d2",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/fa023617-1585-4ae6-81b6-1a07c47ecb2a",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/61782e1c-67a2-487c-8324-6431c628cad8",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/b16e94f3-ad3b-4e3b-9fad-0ef3d2a0958e",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/37e7091f-9ebc-4ac8-875b-5c88f7e5fba8",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/a63b6cc9-899c-447d-b0e6-d1e439379eb2",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/d2d3df43-65c4-499e-90d2-22a157cc7dea",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/9cb95cac-4a0d-4fbb-9237-544a99f29b57",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/7cf87b52-47e3-4d12-8890-53a910792b70"
]
```

Normally, when a promise is resolved, it should return a JSON object, has seen when you enter one of those URLs above in your browser with infos about cover arts for an album release.
So I have tried using Promise.all using this array and see what goes, but I simply can't get something to work : the json() method. I have tried several ways to handle this, found on stackoverflow or elsewhere on the internet, I just always get the `"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response.json is not a function"`
Here are several things I tried :

```
  Promise.all(urlArray)
    .then(toJSON)
    .then((jsonObjects) => console.log(jsonObjects));

  function toJSON(responses) {
    if (!Array.isArray(responses)) {
      // also handle the non array case
      responses = [responses];
    }

    return Promise.all(responses.map((response) => response.json()));
  }
```

Same thing I guess but without helper

```
    Promise.all(urlArray)
      .then((res) => {
        const responses = res.map((response) => response.json());
        return Promise.all(responses);
      })
      .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

The worst thing is, I did manage to do it a few days ago, then changed my mind about how to go with this, and I just can't find how I solved this the first time around. If you guys have any idea what I'm doing wrong, don't hesitate to point it out and scold me about it !
Cheers

Comment: You are passing an array carrying URLs to the static method Promise.all. instead you should have passed array of promise objects. I think you missed the part of making ajax call. You should do something like Promis.all(urlArray.map((url)=>makeAjaxAndReturnPromise(url))) and implement your makeAjaxAndReturnPromise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `urlArray` is an array of *plain strings*, not an array of requests. You never actually make any network requests in your code - you don't have any Promises.

Map the array of request URLs to an array of Promises first.

```js
const urlArray = [
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/985adeec-a1fd-4e79-899d-10c54b6af299",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/4c54ee58-86df-3ba5-aaad-6b284293141b",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/cd8e5736-ec8c-3c4d-a231-ac097877d87a",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/b9b7641f-9389-342e-8be9-e463bd52fdb9",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/b6206cad-15eb-3a95-b67e-1f49849e5fbd",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/db425753-965f-4881-955b-8cd3ef65d1e6",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/fa4f230a-e78c-32a8-bec8-3a7425aba9d2",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/fa023617-1585-4ae6-81b6-1a07c47ecb2a",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/61782e1c-67a2-487c-8324-6431c628cad8",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/b16e94f3-ad3b-4e3b-9fad-0ef3d2a0958e",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/37e7091f-9ebc-4ac8-875b-5c88f7e5fba8",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/a63b6cc9-899c-447d-b0e6-d1e439379eb2",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/d2d3df43-65c4-499e-90d2-22a157cc7dea",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/9cb95cac-4a0d-4fbb-9237-544a99f29b57",
  "https://coverartarchive.org/release/7cf87b52-47e3-4d12-8890-53a910792b70"
]

Promise.all(
  urlArray.map(
    url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
  )
)
  .then((results) => {
    console.log('got all results');
    // use results here
  });
```